# Qt: Is this the proper way to exit for a consumer in a producer-consumer pattern?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

The Producer:

```
// it is in the GUI thread
...

MtileLoadQueue.lock();
  {
      if(!tileLoadQueue.contains(task))
         {
           MtileToload.lock();
           ++tilesToload;
           MtileToload.unlock();
           tileLoadQueue.enqueue(task);
           loaderLimit.release();//loaderLimit is a semaphore
          }
     }
     MtileLoadQueue.unlock();
```

The consumer it subclass a QThread:

```
consumer::run(){
    while (!finish)
        {
            loaderLimit.acquire();//loaderLimit is a semaphore

            LoadTask task;

            MtileLoadQueue.lock();
            {
                if (tileLoadQueue.count() > 0)
                {
                    task = tileLoadQueue.dequeue();
                }
            }
            MtileLoadQueue.unlock();
            //deal with the task...
           Mfinish.lock();
           finish = quit; //quit is initialized as false 
           Mfinish.unlock();
       }
}
```

and When I want the consumer QThread to finish its task (to allow the run function to return) I did this (from the GUI thread):

```
    Mquit.lock();
    quit = true;
    Mquit.unlock();
    loaderLimit.release();
    wait();
```

Then the run() function could return and the consumer thread finish its work.

How correct is this method? Is there better solutions on how to quit the consumer thread since I worried if there could be a chance for deadlock on exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon the type of elements of the queue, there can be a number of solutions.

- If the elements are pointers — **and** `nullptr` can never be a valid object, then maybe the producer could add `nullptr` (usually referred to as *poision* object) to the queue, so as to notify the  consumer(s) to exit. Note that if there are many consumers, then each consumer must add `nullptr` to the queue again before exiting, so that other consumers can be notified.
- If the elements are polymorphic objects (pointers<sup>1</sup> or references), then the producer could use an object of `poison_task` to notify consumers.
- If the elements are neither pointers nor *polymorphic* references, then:

  - the producer could use a sentinel value to notify.
  - the element type could be `boost::optional<T>` where an empty optional value can be used as poison object.
  - the element type could be `std::pair<bool,T>` where the `.first` says whether `.second` is a valid object, or a poison. Note that in this case, `T` must be default constructible.

Use whatever suits your case.

<sup>1.Note that in this case, you could use `nullptr`, as the objects are pointers.</sup>

Comment: So I just check if the task is a nullptr, then I simply call break? And during exit, I just add a nullptr to the taskqueue?

Answer (score 1):

If the worker thread is polling the status variable and evaluates it, yes this is a possibility. However, the GUI-thread could set it directly:

```
InstanceOfWorkerThread->m_quit = true; //quit is bad symbol as reserved by QThread itself
```

This is the way to politely ask the thread to terminate. The thread could ignore the "suggestion". Also, it will terminate only when it evaluates next time the quit-variable.

You could also stop the thread by calling one of:

```
void    QThread::exit ( int returnCode = 0 )
void    QThread::quit ()
void    QThread::terminate ()
```

Comment: Actually during exit, I write one more
loaderLimit.release(); hoping this will guarantee the thread will get the chance to change the "finish" state and then finish properlly. But just not sure whether this is good enough (any possible failure like racing conditions or else?)